# how to post checkbox to action in Yii?

Tags: php, checkbox, yii

I want to post a checkbox to action and print alert if the checkbox is checked, here is my code:

view:

```
echo CHtml::checkBox('hi');
echo CHtml::button('Search', array('onclick' => 'js:document.location.href="index"'));
```

controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {

            $model = Jobs::model()->findAll();
            $model2 = Tags::model()->findAll();


            if(isset($_POST['hi']))
                        echo "<script>alert('hello');</script>";


            $this->render('index', array('model'=>$model, 'model2'=>$model2));
    }
```

when I check the checkbox and click the button nothing is happened, where is the error in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just redirect your page to `actionIndex`. You must `SUBMIT` your form instead of redirecting it. Take a look:

```
    echo CHtml::beginForm(Yii::app()->createUrl('index'), 'POST');
    echo CHtml::checkBox('hi');
    echo CHtml::submitButton('Search');
    echo CHtml::endForm();
```

If you try:

```
CVarDumper::dump($_POST,56789,true);
```

You can see the `POST` value after submitting the form.

Or you can do it via java-script in your button:

```
//if you have created a form
echo CHtml::button('Search', array('onclick' => 'this.submit();'));
```